# Turtle keybinds, why do they keep crashing?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
#Turtle messing around
import turtle
import os


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")

border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(0)
border.penup()
border.color("blue")
border.setposition(-200,-200)
border.setheading(90)
border.pensize(3)
border.pendown()
for x in range(4):
border.fd(400)
border.rt(90)
border.penup()
border.fd(300)
border.rt(90)
border.hideturtle()

#Player graphics
player= turtle.Turtle()
player.setposition(0,-150)
player.color("white")
player.left(90)
player.shape("triangle")
player.shapesize(1)
player.speed(0)
player.penup()
turtle.mainloop()

playerspeed = 15


#Player movement
def moveleft():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = -280
        player.setx(x)
def moveright():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > -280:
        x = 280
        player.setx(x)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(moveleft, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(moveright, "Right")


turtle.mainloop()
```

My code is above.

Whenever I run it the normal program doesn't do anything (I've tried replacing the last three `wn`'s with `turtle`).

But when I close the window another one pops up (Only when last three are turtle) and I get the following error:

```
     ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REDACTED", line 54, in <module>
    wn.listen()
  File "G:\python\lib\turtle.py", line 1438, in listen
    self._listen()
  File "G:\python\lib\turtle.py", line 710, in _listen
    self.cv.focus_force()
  File "G:\python\lib\turtle.py", line 426, in focus_force
    self._canvas.focus_force()
  File "G:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 428, in focus_force
    self.tk.call('focus', '-force', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "focus" command:  application has been 
destroyed
```

I'm not really sure what to do here, all that error stuff is confusing to me and I don't understand, I appreciate all the help I can get, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on line 34. When you call `turtle.mainloop()`, the program enters an infinite loop; none of the code on lines below it will execute, including your event listeners.

```
# ... unchanged code ...

player.speed(0)
player.penup()
turtle.mainloop()  # <--- infinite loop! remove this line.

# code below this line is not executed
playerspeed = 15

# ... unchanged code ...
```

Remove this line and you'll see your handlers firing (add debug prints if you're not sure). Your second `turtle.mainloop()` call on the last line will correctly run the window.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you your first mistake: on line 13 where you say `for x in range(4):`
the indent did not apply there. you have to indent when you have loops, otherwise you will get an error.

This is what I got when I copied your code and removed the `turtle.mainloop()`:
 click the link to see it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI3Lg.gif

Also, the `turtle.mainloop()` part doesn't do anything except keep it in an infinite loop.

If you absolutely want it there, the put it at the end.